# RegEx match unserscore chatacters in strings not starting with @

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx that matches all underscore characters but should not match ones in strings starting with an `@` character.

What I've gotten until now is a RegEx with a negative lookbeind which only ignores the first underscore in strings starting with a `@` character: `/(?<!@)_/gi`.

Playground with test data: https://regex101.com/r/Hd8IeX/1/

Comment: Would `^@.*(*SKIP)(*F)|_` work for you?

Comment: @JvdV this seems to also match underscores which are contained in a word starting with an @ 
https://regex101.com/r/8ob2bu/1

Comment: You got to use the right [flags](https://regex101.com/r/8ob2bu/3) @Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^@.*(*SKIP)(*F)|_
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hd8IeX/2). You just had to use the right flags.

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `@` - Literally match "@".
- `.*` - Match anything other than newline (greedy).
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - Fail any match up to that point.
- `|` - Or:
- `_` - Match an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment, could this work:

```
^@.*|[^\w]@.*(*SKIP)(*F)|_
```

Comment: In my opinion `[^\w]@.*(*SKIP)(*F)|_` should be sufficient. Be aware that `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` only work in Perl flavored Regex (mainly perl and php). Other Regex engines will not support this syntax.